# Howto change the fontsize of an attributes array (swift, ios)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function as follow, which creates an attributes array. I like to reuse this attributes for lot of textdrawing.

```
func getFontAttributes(fTextSize:CGFloat, color:UIColor, alignment:String) -> [NSObject : AnyObject]{


    let fieldFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: fTextSize)
    var paraStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

    paraStyle.lineSpacing = 6.0
    if (alignment=="left"){
    paraStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Left;
    }else if(alignment=="right"){
        paraStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Right;
    }else{
        paraStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
    }

    var skew = 0.1

    let attributes = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color,
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paraStyle,
        NSObliquenessAttributeName: skew,
        NSFontAttributeName: fieldFont!
    ]
    return attributes;

}
```

How can I change only one single attribute of my attributes (for example fontsize) afterwards ? I don't like to call my function getFontAttributes again.

```
let attributes=getFontAttributes(14, UIColor.darkGrayColor(),"left");
attributes.setFontSize(16); // <----- Howto do ?
```

I am pretty sure this must be possible but I am stuck with syntax and typeconversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dictionary and not an array. Also every time you call this fucntion you get a new instance of this dictionary.

So you can just call it once:

```
var attrDict = getFontAttributes(14, UIColor.darkGrayColor(),"left")
```

and then just do:

```
attrDict[NSFontAttributeName] = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: newSize)
```

Comment: Perfect. That works ! This gives me a new view to dictionaries in ios. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just change the size of existing font this code will help.

First create variable with attributes:

```
var attributes = getFontAttributes(14.0, color: UIColor.darkGrayColor(), alignment: "left");
```

And then you can change font size like this:

```
attributes[NSFontAttributeName] = attributes[NSFontAttributeName]?.fontWithSize(16)
```